# How do i add in a fixed position column into my sql query?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, localhost

I have a teams table

```
CREATE TABLE teams(id int primary key auto_increment,tname char(32) unique);
```

I also have a games table

```
CREATE TABLE games(id int primary key auto_increment, date datetime,
               hteam int, ateam int, hscore tinyint,ascore tinyint);
```

This is an sql query i have that displays the league standings

```
SELECT
tname AS Team, Sum(P) AS P,Sum(W) AS W,Sum(D) AS D,Sum(L) AS L,
SUM(F) as F,SUM(A) AS A,SUM(GD) AS GD,SUM(Pts) AS Pts
FROM(
SELECT
hteam Team,
1 P,
IF(hscore > ascore,1,0) W,
IF(hscore = ascore,1,0) D,
IF(hscore < ascore,1,0) L,
hscore F,
ascore A,
hscore-ascore GD,
CASE WHEN hscore > ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS
FROM games
UNION ALL
SELECT
ateam,
1,
IF(hscore < ascore,1,0),
IF(hscore = ascore,1,0),
IF(hscore > ascore,1,0),
ascore,
hscore,
ascore-hscore GD,
CASE WHEN hscore < ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM games
) as tot
JOIN teams t ON tot.Team=t.id
GROUP BY Team
ORDER BY SUM(Pts) DESC, SUM(GD) DESC, SUM(F) DESC;
```

Its probably straight forward but i cant seem to figure it out, how do i add in a 'positions' column represented as 'POS' on the far left hand side of the league table that will display each teams ranking within the table, like an auto-increment?

Thanks! :)

UPDATE:

I have managed to get a rank column to work along the left hand side of the league table, but it shows the teams corresponding id as opposed to their ranking within the league table.

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, tname AS Team, Sum(P) AS P,Sum(W) AS 
W,Sum(D) AS D,Sum(L) AS L,
SUM(F) as F,SUM(A) AS A,SUM(GD) AS GD,SUM(Pts) AS Pts
FROM(
SELECT
hteam Team,
1 P,
IF(hscore > ascore,1,0) W,
IF(hscore = ascore,1,0) D,
IF(hscore < ascore,1,0) L,
hscore F,
ascore A,
hscore-ascore GD,
CASE WHEN hscore > ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS
FROM games
UNION ALL
SELECT
ateam,
1,
IF(hscore < ascore,1,0),
IF(hscore = ascore,1,0),
IF(hscore > ascore,1,0),
ascore,
hscore,
ascore-hscore GD,
CASE WHEN hscore < ascore THEN 3 WHEN hscore = ascore THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM games
) as tot
JOIN teams t ON tot.Team=t.id
GROUP BY Team
ORDER BY SUM(Pts) DESC, SUM(GD) DESC, SUM(F) DESC;
```

Comment: Which league? Goal difference is ranked differently in different leagues.

Comment: Its based off the English Premier League

Comment: In that, the answer below is more or less correct, but could be expressed more eloquently. Incidentally, the query above looks very familiar ;-)